# Firebase realtime database - permission denied when reading a path if the value is null

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to read a path in my Firebase Realtime database `/users/uid1` where the value at the path is `null`. In effect, it does not exist. My security rules allow reading at the path (rules below). When actually reading data, permission is denied.

**Security rules are as follows:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').child($uid).child('mUser_Role').child('mRole_PermissionLevel').val() > 400 || root.child('users').child(auth.token.phone_number).child('mUser_Role').child('mRole_PermissionLevel').val() == 500"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to read `/users/uid1` with `/users/myuid/mUser_Role/mRole_PermissionLevel == 500` being `true` fails with permission denied.

How does Firebase determine that permission should be denied for the case when value is `null` ? Shouldn't this read be allowed and return a `dataSnapshot` where  `dataSnapshot.exists()` returns `false` ?

I have not specified any rules around `data` at the path being `null` and the read succeeds when the value at the path is not `null`

---

**EDIT - To re-produce this scenario -**

**1. Upload JSON to the root of a Firebase realtime db-**

```
{
  "users" : {
    "+9198100xxxxx" : {
      "mUser_Id" : "+9198100xxxxx",
      "mUser_ProfilePicUrl" : "url",
      "mUser_Role" : {
        "mRole_Name" : "Employee",
        "mRole_PermissionLevel" : 500
      }
    },
    "+9198100yyyyy" : {
      "mUser_Id" : "+9198100yyyyy",
      "mUser_ProfilePicUrl" : "url",
      "mUser_Role" : {
        "mRole_Name" : "Employee",
        "mRole_PermissionLevel" : 500
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Firebase realtime db rules (actually using for this node) -**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').child($uid).child('mUser_Role').child('mRole_PermissionLevel').val() > 400 || root.child('users').child(auth.token.phone_number).child('mUser_Role').child('mRole_PermissionLevel').val() == 500"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**3. Use Firbease security rules simulator -**

Simulation type - `read`

Location - `/users/+9198100zzzzz` (simulated read fails)

Location - `/users/+9198100yyyyy` (simulated read succeeds)

Authenticated - `yes`

Provider - `custom`

Auth token payload -

```
{
  "provider": "phoneauth",
  "uid": "6f2eed52-b2e9-409a-b5f1-dc307c7f6671",
  "token":{
      "phone_number": "+9198100xxxxx"
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to include the minimum JSON and (standalone) code with which you can reproduce the problem? In the code, be sure to print the UID and phone number of the user, right before you try to read the data, so that we have all information necessary to troubleshoot.

Comment: It looks like you're using `auth.token.phone_number` in your rule instead of `auth.uid`.  Is that intentional?  Your question suggests you want to use the uid in the path, and says nothing about phone number.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks. I am intentionally using `auth.token.phone_number` in the rule. The user IDs in the database are the same as phone numbers. Also, I am using phone authentication. My security rule gets the `phone_number` from the `auth.token` in the request, then checks the permission level at the path corresponding to that user ID in the database (where user ID is same as `phone_number`).Hence the path in the rule. I am not using `auth.uid` as a user ID in the database

@FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. I'll get back with this as soon as I can

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the minimum JSON and a standalone way to reproduce this using Firebase realtime db security rules simulator (along with the params used in the simulator). Thanks

Comment: Hmm.... the operation in that last screenshot should also be rejected, shouldn't it?

Comment: Updated the question with simpler rules This particular condition seems to be the problem: root.child('users').child($uid).child('mUser_Role').child('mRole_PermissionLevel').val() > 400. If value at /users/$uid is null (screenshot 1) the read is denied even though the last condition after the `OR` evaluates to true (root.child('users').child(auth.token.phone_number).child('mUser_Role').child('mRole_PermissionLevel').val() == 500). @FrankvanPuffelen I expect both reads to succeed as the condition after the `OR` evaluates to true in both cases

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm actually not sure what the expected behavior for non-existing nodes is. Let me ask around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-existent nodes evaluate to `null`, so your rule essentially evaluates to:

```
null > 400 || 500 == 500
```

The rules engine used is strongly typed, which means that `null > 400` raises an error instead of evaluating to `false`.

The solution is to first check for the existence of the node, before comparing its value. So:

```
".read": "
 (
  root.child('users').child($uid).exists() &&
  root.child('users').child($uid).child('mUser_Role').child('mRole_PermissionLevel').val() > 400
 ) || (
  root.child('users').child(auth.token.phone_number).exists() &&
  root.child('users').child(auth.token.phone_number).child('mUser_Role').child('mRole_PermissionLevel').val() == 500
 )
"
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I'll put in the null checks then